# PyCharm Jupyter notebook No module named 'toolbox'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am trying to install `toolbox` and it shows the below error. I already updated the setup-toolbox but I still get this error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

While installing toolbox from pycharm it shows this error:
`FileNotFoundError:No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\toolbox\\setup.py'`

Installing via command line it show:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-j5ja0k9r\toolbox\.`

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have done so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading the console:

```
pip install -U jupyter_console
```

You can also download manually from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/)